# Drawing directed graph represented by an array of lists

Tags: data-structures, graph, graph-theory, directed-graph, representation

Morning,
This was one of my exam questions for data structures and algorithms.

I have to draw a graph on paper based on below array of lists:
[image: graph]

The problem I have encountered, is for example:

0->1->4->3

What does it exactly mean? Does it mean 0 has 3 edges to 1 and 4 and 3, or is it just a collection of edges, for example, 0 has edge to 1, 1 has edge to 4, 4 has edge to 3, and so on.
I'd appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are talking about is called "Linked representation" in graph-theory.

`0->1->4->3` means that the vertex 0 is connected to 1 and 4 and 3 in a directed way(means arrow is directed from 0 to vertex 1,vertex 4 and vertex 3 respectively).That means that there are three directed edges coming out of vertex 0 to vertices 1,4 and 3 respectively **(PLEASE MIND THAT THESE EDGES ARE DIRECTED AS PER YOUR SAYING)**!

Similarly,1 simply alone emphasises that there is no directed edge from vertex 1 to any other vertices.

Similarly,`2->1` means that there is an edge directed from vertex 2 to vertex 1.

And,`3->0->4` means that vertex 3 is directing the edges towards both vertex 0 and vertex 4.

Lastly, `4->2->0` means that there is an edge directed from vertex 4 to both vertex 2 and vertex 0 each.